# Parse load Images Swift 3.0

Tags: parse-platform, uiimage, backend, swift3

I'm runnig my own parse server and all works fine but 
I can't convert A PFFile to a UIImage, this is the error it throws at me:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSData?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type PFDataResultBlock'

Here is the code I used:

```
var imageFromParse = object.object(forKey: "ProfilePicture") as! PFFile!
                        imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            var image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                        })
```

And all of this used to work perfectly in Swift 2.3.
thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.0:

```
if let imageFromParse = user.object(forKey: "ProfilePicture") as? PFFile {
    imageFromParse.getDataInBackground(block: {
        (data: Data?, error: Error?) in

        if error == nil {

        }
    })

}
```

Main updates:

(data: **NSData**?, error: **NSError**?) in

has been updated to:

(data: **Data**?, error: **Error**?) in

And:

Swift 3 makes all labels required unless you specify otherwise, which means the method names no longer detail their parameters. In practice, this often means the last part of the method name gets moved to be the name of the first parameter. 
Find out more at: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3

Comment: I found that using the shortened version of the signature is much easier: "(data, error) in".

Answer (score 2):

Use `Data` and `Error` instead of `NSData` and `NSError`

Answer (score 1):

i did some test on swift 3.0 and the following code works for me:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "FileTest")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let firstObject = objects?.first as PFObject!
        let objectFile = firstObject.objectForKey("file") as! PFFile
        objectFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            if image != nil {
                self.imageOutlet.image = image
            }

        })
    }
```

In this code i first fetch all the **FileTest** collection, then i take the first object (just for test of course) and then i read the file. please notice that i an using **objectForKey** in order to get the PFFile which exist under the test column. After i have the file i call **getDataInBackground** to get the data, create UIImage from the data and update my imageView 
Everything works as expected.. 
try to run this code and see if it works for you.

Comment: It wont even allow me to use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` xcode changes it to `findObjectsInBackground` It's really odd, Are you using the Latest Parse SDK?

Comment: Yes I added parse via cocoapods

Comment: weird, cause it has been renamed to `findObjectsInBackground(block:)` but i can't find anything in the documentation to handle this...

Comment: Can you add parse with cocoapods? What I can do also is to upload my project to github so you can clone it and test if it works for you ..